# pymssql on RHEL 6.5 - freetds installed using source in /opt/app/freetds

Tags: python, python-2.7, gcc, pip, pymssql

G'day All,

I am trying to install pymssql on RHEL 6.5.

I downloaded freetds source from their website and installed it.

```
cd /opt/app
tar xfz /Prerequisites/freetds-stable.tgz
cd /opt/app/freetds-0.91
./configure --prefix=/opt/app/freetds
make
make install
```

Following this, I am trying to install pymssql using this command but it fails.

Apparently, it is not able to find the necessary headers and libs that are supposed to be in /opt/app/freetds/include and /opt/app/freetds/lib folder.

What can i do to go past this issue?

Please guide.

```
[gdd@svr /Prerequisites]$pip install pymssql-2.1.1.tar.gz --no-index --find-links /Prerequisites
Ignoring indexes: https://pypi.python.org/simple
Processing ./pymssql-2.1.1.tar.gz
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server', '6.5', 'Santiago')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.2.5')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
Installing collected packages: pymssql
  Running setup.py install for pymssql
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'
    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')
    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server', '6.5', 'Santiago')
    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.2.5')
    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS
    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']
    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    building '_mssql' extension
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/app/Python2.7.9/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB
    gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/app/Python2.7.9/lib -lsybdb -lrt -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.so
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsybdb
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /opt/app/Python2.7.9/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-nO5nuo-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-tEZz4T-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    setup.py: platform.system() => 'Linux'


    setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')


    setup.py: platform.linux_distribution() => ('Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server', '6.5', 'Santiago')


    setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.2.5')


    setup.py: Not using bundled FreeTDS


    setup.py: include_dirs = ['/usr/local/include']


    setup.py: library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']


    running install


    running build


    running build_ext


    building '_mssql' extension


    creating build


    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7


    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/app/Python2.7.9/include/python2.7 -c _mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB


    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7


    gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/app/Python2.7.9/lib -lsybdb -lrt -lpython2.7 -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/_mssql.so


    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsybdb


    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status


    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1


    ----------------------------------------
    Command "/opt/app/Python2.7.9/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-nO5nuo-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-tEZz4T-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-nO5nuo-build
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the tip from runciter @ IRC #python . . . I was able to solve this as below

```
export CFLAGS='-I/opt/app/freetds/include' 
export LDFLAGS='-L/opt/app/freetds/lib'
pip install /Prerequisites/pymssql-2.1.1.tar.gz --no-index --find-links /Prerequisites
```